VS Code doesn't pass arguments in Flutter?
Regarding to 
I have created a configuration in launch.json
        {
            "name": "my_upp (debug mode command-line)",
            "cwd": "my_upp",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "flutterMode": "debug",
            "args": [
                "-h",
                "127.0.0.1",
                "-p",
                "3050",
                "-df",
                "C:\\DB.FDB"
            ]
        },

When I try to run the app, the VS Code output is

Could not find an option or flag "-p".
Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter  -h') for available flutter
commands and options.
Exited (64).

It looks like these args were transferred to flutter launcher, but not to my app.
When I set args as
   "args": [
                "127.0.0.1",
                "3050",
                "C:\\DB.FDB"
            ]

the app is started, but args list is empty

What I do wrong? Thank you in advance.
VS Code version 1.93.0
Flutter version 3.24.2
Dart version 3.5.2

Wow... You're retrieving data arguments using the pre-defined commands. May I know what the exact process flow is, such as what certain tools you're using? The wow word is not intended to mock; I was just really amazed about your question.

What documentation did you get those args param keys?

You are running the configuration from the green arrow on the debug panel, right?  It just worked fine for me.

@DevQt, debug configuration with pre-defined params is used for debugging process only. In real life the app will be started from cli/script with real params, as usual command-line tool

@RandalSchwartz, yes, exactly. I know it should work, but in my case it doesn't

So, confirming again, you're using the "debug start" green triangle, and you have the proper launch.json item selected?  Perphaps you can attach a screencast video of what you are seeing and doing?

@RandalSchwartz, yes, I'm using debug start green triangle button and the proper  launch.json item is selected. Unfortunately, I haven't possibility to record screen video now.
